# Promises messing up?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

This issue has been driving me nuts for the last couple of days. I'm far from being a Javascript expert, maybe the solution is obvious but I don't see it.

What I basically try to do is :

1. download items in paralell, each request being made for a given
   item type (type1, type2) with different properties.
2. Once downloaded, execute a callback function to post-process the data
   (this is the same function with different parameters and with a test
   on the item type in order to have different processing)
3. Save the item

If I download 1 item type, everything is OK. But if I download 2 types, then at some point in the processing loop within the first callback execution, exactly when the callback is executed a 2nd time for the 2nd type, then the test on type will indicate it's the 2nd type, while the items are of the 1st type...

Here is an extract of the code :

```js
downloadType1();
downloadType2();

// 2nd argument of download() is the callback function
// 3rd argument is the callback function parameters
function downloadType1() {
    // Some stuff here
    let callbackParameters = ['type1', 'directory1'];
    download('url', headacheCallback, callbackParameters);
}

function downloadType2() {
    // Some the stuff here
    let callbackParameters = ['type2', 'directory2'];
    download('url', headacheCallback, callbackParameters);
}

async function download(url, callbackBeforeSave, callbackParameters) {
    // Some stuff here
    let response;
    try {
        response = await rp(url);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error downloading data");
    }

    // Call callbacks before saving the data
    if(callbackBeforeSave) {
        let updatedResponse;

        if (callbackParameters) {
            updatedResponse = await callbackBeforeSave(response, ...callbackParameters);
        } else {
            updatedResponse = await callbackBeforeSave(response);
        }

        response = updatedResponse;
    }
    
    // Some stuff here with the post-processed data
}

async function headacheCallback(data, type, directory) {
    for (item of data) {
        // Some stuff here, include async/await calls (mostly to download and save files)
        
        console.log(type, item.propertyToUpdate, item.child.propertyToUpdate);
        // This is were my issue is.
        // The test will success although I'm still the 'type1' loop. I know because the console.log above shows the item is indeed of type 'type1'
        if (type === 'type2') {
            item.child.propertyToUpdate = newUrl; // Will eventually fail because 'type1' items don't have a .child.propertyToUpdate property 
        } else {
            item.propertyToUpdate = newUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

At some point, the output of `console.log` will be :
`type2 <valueOfTheProperty> undefined` which should be `type2 undefined <valueOfTheProperty>`...

A quick thought : in the first version of the callback, I used the `arguments` global variables in combination with `function.apply(...)`. This was bad precisely because `arguments` was global and thus was changed after the 2nd call...

But now I don't see anything global in my code that could explain why `type` is changing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `rp()` defined? What is `.visualLink`?

Comment: Sorry if I was not precise enough, I had to simplify a lot because there is a lot of uninteresting code.

`rp()` makes an HTTP request and returns a promise, it's from [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native).

`.visualLink`is just a property of the downloaded items I want to update in my post-process. There are actually more properties that are updates but again, for the sake of readability, I've kept only this one for the post

Comment: I've changed the name of the property to `propertyToUpdate` so that it's clearer

Comment: Looks like some strange uses of promises here. What functions are a promise in your code? Off the top of my head, it seems weird that downloadType1() and downloadType2() are invoked iteratively, with no .then() or promise.all() or anything. You also don't return the "download" function out of either, so they're returning undefined, and thus couldn't even be .then()'d anyway.

Comment: There's not enough clear information here to do an actual answer (I suspect that's why this post is being downvoted - sometimes stackoverflow thinks it should only exist to answer fundamental questions about language dynamics, not debug someone's code) - but I would recommend looking at: http://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html as well as  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Common_mistakes

Comment: @CalebJay I will try `Promise.all` as you and @4m1r suggested and keep you posted. Indeed `download` doesn't return anything for now but it will eventually return a bool for success/failure. It's basically a wrapper that download, modify and save data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see anything global in my code that could explain why type is changing.

It's not `type` that is changing. Your problem is `item` that is an [involuntary global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html):

```
for (item of data) {
//   ^^^^
```

Make that a

```
for (const item of data) {
//   ^^^^
```

And always enable strict mode!

Comment: Oh come on! I knew it was so stupid... You made my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for Promise.all

```
const p1 = new Promise((res, rej) => res());
Promise.all([p1, p2]).then((results) => results.map(yourFunction));
```

Promise.all will return an array of resolved or may catch on any rejection.  But you don't have to reject if you setup your p1, p2, pn with a new Promise that only resolves.  Then your function map can handle the branching and do the right thing for the right response type.  Make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. As a non-JS developper, I'm still a bit confused with promises and I think my mind don't think in the correct way. But it looks like it could do the job. I'll let you know.